# Clearing text in UITextField - Objective c - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone please let me know how to bring the clear option ('X' symbol) in the UITextField in objective c ? I have attached an image for your perusal. I want the 'x' symbol shown in the image to clear the text.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Interface Builder, when you select the text field, in the atturbutes inspector (on the right), there should be an option for `Clear Button`. One of the options is "Appears While Editing," plus a few others.

In code, see the answer by @Shashank.

Answer (score 5):

```
 myUITextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
```